# How to see web socket requests in Charles Proxy

Tags: ios, sockets, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm using a free version (3.11.5 as of this writing) of Charles Proxy and proxying my iPhone through it to attempt to reverse engineer some real-time features of an app I'm using.

I'm successfully able to see all http/https request in and out of the device. There are, however, web sockets (was://) that are open on the app that I cant see. It's only listing http/https requests.

Is there a setting I'm missing? Is the free version limited? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the app you are proxying is not using the proxy settings you have defined in your iPhone’s “Settings”. If this is the case, you’d need a version of the app which adheres to the user defined proxy settings in order to see the WebSocket traffic in Charles.

Comment: How would you look up what your iPhone or Simulator's proxy settings are?

Comment: @Trip  in Settings: General > About > Certificate Trust Settings,